# Game only runs at 60fps in windowed mode with a 120hz monitor?

Tags: directx11, slimdx, vsync

In fullscreen the game will run at 120fps fine, the correct refresh rate for the monitor, but in windowed mode it only runs at 60fps.  If I disable VSync then it runs at thounsands of fps so it's not a case of a lack of performance.  I've correctly set the refresh rate in the ModeDescription.

Comment: In windowed mode, you don't have exclusion control over the device.

Comment: When you say "I've correctly set the refresh rate in the ModeDescription" can you confirm - did you just set Numerator to 120 and Denominator to 1, or did you actually use a refresh rate obtained via IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList?

Comment: I was using 120 and 1, GetDisplayModeList keeps returning null for me?

Answer (score 4):

In windowed mode in Windows Vista and Windows 7, as well as OS X and many modern Linux desktop incarnations, the application has *zero* control over refresh.  The application's front buffer is really just another off-screen surface used by a compositing system, like `dwm.exe` in Windows, which then composites the final full desktop image.  It may run at a different frame rate than you want, and your application's rendering may be limited to that rate (since it has no reason or ability to worry about the monitor's native rate).

Comment: How come I don't get this problem on many other games?